# what next after 'dive into python'

Tags: python

I've been meaning to learn another language than java.  So I started to poke around with python.  I've gone over 'dive into python' so I have a decent knowledge about python now.

where do you suggest I go from here? I dont want to go through another advanced book again and would like to use the python knowledge towards building 'something'.

I've heard that python is good for web crawling, however, I did not see that in dive into python.  Can the community suggest how to use my pythong knowledge towards web crawlers or spiders?

Answer (score 12):

That really kind of depends on what you enjoy, or would like to build.  Since you haven't said, I'll recommend something I enjoyed instead.  [Programming Collective Intelligence](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325) by Toby Segaran is a fun book, and the examples are all in Python.  It might be more interesting to you -- if nothing else, it would give your web crawler something to do with the pages it gathers.

Edit: Fusspawn's suggestion of PyGame is very good, if don't want any more books and just want to "dive in" to something.

Comment: Thanks, I had come across that book but did not know that the examples were in python

Answer (score 7):

You can try my [Building Skills in OO Design](http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/books/oodesign.html).

http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/books/oodesign.html

Comment: Link is munged -- the "_" gets escaped improperly.

Comment: +1 for being awesome enough to have your own book to recommend to others =P

Answer (score 5):

If you like math try learning Python by solving [Project Euler problems](http://projecteuler.net/) using python. Each problem is not too much code and it helped me increase my python skills.

Comment: This will increase your math skills and your general algorithm ability as well.

Answer (score 4):

I always find making a small game is a nice way to learn a language 
[PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/) makes it simple and could help learn more about python. I suggest giving it ago if your that way inclined.

Answer (score 4):

To get started with web crawling, consider the Scrapy framework.

http://scrapy.org/

"Scrapy is a high level scraping and web crawling framework for writing spiders to crawl and parse web pages for all kinds of purposes, from information retrieval to monitoring or testing web sites."

It's still edging towards a first release, but is usable and has decent documentation.

For very basic web scraping, check out Mechanize (for basic web "browsing") and BeautifulSoup (for parsing "html soup"):

http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

One fun thing to do would be to combine these interests with some natural language processing projects.  The NLTK book recently published by O'Reilly is available online as well:

http://www.nltk.org/book

Lots of fun to be had combining these interests. :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to expand beyond web crawling and don't want to start a your own project (or don't know what to do), check out [The Python Challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/). It's a game where you have to solve puzzles with a bit of python code. I really enjoyed it.

Comment: Just started with Python but these challenges are really good fun. A nice way to get familiar with different areas of the language

Answer (score 3):

Is web crawling something you want to do or just something you think you can accomplish?  Python is a good tool for web crawling(see [here](http://www.drewconway.com/zia/?p=1037) and [here](http://www.drewconway.com/zia/?p=1096)), but if you really just want ANY project to work on to get more familiar to the language/APIs I'd suggest you pick a project that you have a general interest in regardless.  That way it'll be easier to stick with to fruition as you already have an interest in the project in addition to an interest in the language.

Comment: This is good advice. Don't choose something you think it's good at, choose something you want to do (medieval torture tools database, knitting pattern designer, whatever whets your whistle). Then do it. It may well be that what you choose doesn't fit well with the Python way of doing things. It may even be that your "product" is rubbish. That's irrelevant. You'll learn a lot about Python *and* it's something you're not likely to get bored with.

Answer (score 3):

Find an interesting open source project to participate in. You could start looking on [pythonsource](http://pythonsource.com/) or [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

The [Tools/webchecker/](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Tools/webchecker/) directory, which should be in your Python distribution (otherwise you can get it via the link I gave), is a start -- with lots of limitations (no threading except in `wsgui.py`, no async operation, ...), but removing some of them would be a great learning experience!

A vastly superior spidering system could be built on top of Twisted, e.g. starting with the snippet at the bottom of [this mail](http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2003-July/005063.html) (which only gets one page, but in the proper asynchronous way!) and adding the other functionality you see exemplified in webchecker (parse and respect robots.txt, get links from pages, etc, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna "advanced book", I recommend Alex's [Python in a Nutshell, Second Edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596100469/), learn quite a lot from the book, and Tarek's [Expert Python Programming](http://www.packtpub.com/expert-python-programming/book),we all know it's a advanced book for it's title:) .
For read some open source project, recommend [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/).
Maybe try to start you own project is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Others have said it but I'll repeat: work on something you are interested in or it won't be fun.

If you do decide that a crawler would be fun, take a look at [`google-kongulo`](http://code.google.com/p/google-kongulo/), web spider plugin for Google desktop search. The code is quite short and well-written, so this might make a good base for when you decide what you want to crawl.

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifically interested in crawling the Web, check out the three-part talk called "Scrape the Web" given at PyCon 2009. It's part of this [RSS feed](http://advocacy.python.org/podcasts/pycon.rss).

Answer (score 0):

Read *Dive Into Python* again, it discusses [HTML processing](http://www.diveintopython.net/html_processing/index.html) and [HTTP web services](http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/index.html) in chapters 8 and 11.